# How do I view an embedded RavenDB database?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

RavenDB server comes with a web UI Studio letting to look what's inside. But what's the way to take a look in an embedded RavenDB?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a test you can use the [WaitForUserToContinueTheTest](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Tests.Helpers/RavenTestBase.cs#L774) method. Otherwise I guess you'll need to start the http server yourself.